# Why is my ListView-Item only jumping back to VisualState Selected, once?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, xaml, uwp, visualstatemanager

I have a problem with my ListView in my UWP-Application. When selecting an Item the first time, after MouseOver ends it's VisualState changes to "Selected" as it should, but when I select it a second time, after I selected another Item, it stayes in VisualState "Pressed" even after MouseOver until I select the next Item. So my Item switches only once to the desired VisualState, to iggnore this State for the rest of the session.
What could be the reason for this behaviour, and could this be unique to UWP, since I do not remember having seen something like this before.

This is my ListView, as I use it in Xaml right now:

```
<ListView IsItemClickEnabled="True"
            Grid.Row="1"
            Grid.Column="1"
            ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollMode="Auto"
            ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto"
            ItemsSource="{Binding Path=list, Mode=OneWay}"
            ItemTemplate="{StaticResource RepVSmallIcon70ItemTemplate}"
            TabIndex="1"
            SelectedIndex="{Binding Path=selectedIndex, Mode=TwoWay}"
            SelectionChanged="ListView_SelectionChanged"
            IsRightTapEnabled="False"
            ItemContainerStyle="{StaticResource ListViewItemStyleUWP}"/>
```

which uses this ItemContainerStyle:

```
<Style x:Key="ListViewItemStyleUWP" TargetType="ListViewItem">
    <Setter Property="FontFamily" Value="{ThemeResource ContentControlThemeFontFamily}"/>
    <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="{ThemeResource ControlContentThemeFontSize}"/>
    <Setter Property="Background" Value="MediumOrchid"/>
    <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="{ThemeResource SystemControlForegroundBaseHighBrush}"/>
    <Setter Property="TabNavigation" Value="Local"/>
    <Setter Property="IsHoldingEnabled" Value="True"/>
    <Setter Property="Padding" Value="12,0,12,0"/>
    <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Left"/>
    <Setter Property="VerticalContentAlignment" Value="Center"/>
    <Setter Property="MinWidth" Value="160"/>
    <Setter Property="MinHeight" Value="100"/>
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="ListViewItem">
                <Border x:Name="OuterContainer" RenderTransformOrigin="0.5,0.5">
                    <VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                        <VisualStateGroup x:Name="CommonStates">
                            <VisualState x:Name="Normal">
                                <!-- unselektiert -->
                                <Storyboard>
                                    <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Duration="0"
                                                                Storyboard.TargetName="ContentBorder"
                                                                Storyboard.TargetProperty="BorderBrush">
                                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="Orange"/>
                                    </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                    <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Duration="0"
                                                                Storyboard.TargetName="ContentBorder"
                                                                Storyboard.TargetProperty="Background">
                                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="LightBlue"/>
                                    </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                    <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Duration="0"
                                                                Storyboard.TargetName="ContentBorder"
                                                                Storyboard.TargetProperty="Margin">
                                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="0 0 0 2"/>
                                    </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                </Storyboard>
                            </VisualState>
                            <VisualState x:Name="Pressed">
                                <!-- Klick -->
                                <Storyboard>
                                    <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Duration="0"
                                                                Storyboard.TargetName="ContentBorder"
                                                                Storyboard.TargetProperty="BorderBrush">
                                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="Red"/>
                                    </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                    <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Duration="0"
                                                                Storyboard.TargetName="ContentBorder"
                                                                Storyboard.TargetProperty="Background">
                                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="Blue"/>
                                    </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                    <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Duration="0"
                                                                Storyboard.TargetName="ContentBorder"
                                                                Storyboard.TargetProperty="Margin">
                                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="2 2 2 4"/>
                                    </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                </Storyboard>
                            </VisualState>
                        </VisualStateGroup>
                        <VisualStateGroup x:Name="SelectionStates">
                            <VisualState x:Name="Selected">
                                    <!--Selektiert--> 
                                <Storyboard>
                                    <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Duration="0"
                                                                Storyboard.TargetName="ContentBorder"
                                                                Storyboard.TargetProperty="BorderBrush">
                                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="DarkRed"/>
                                    </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                    <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Duration="0"
                                                                Storyboard.TargetName="ContentBorder"
                                                                Storyboard.TargetProperty="Background">
                                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="DarkBlue"/>
                                    </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                    <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Duration="0"
                                                                Storyboard.TargetName="ContentBorder"
                                                                Storyboard.TargetProperty="Margin">
                                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="0 0 0 2"/>
                                    </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                </Storyboard>
                            </VisualState>
                        </VisualStateGroup>
                    </VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                    <Grid x:Name="ReorderHintContent" Background="Transparent">
                        <Border x:Name="ContentContainer">
                            <Border x:Name="ContentBorder"
                                    Background="LightCyan"
                                    BorderBrush="DarkCyan"
                                    BorderThickness="2">
                                <Grid>
                                    <ContentPresenter x:Name="contentPresenter"
                                                        ContentTransitions="{TemplateBinding ContentTransitions}"
                                                        ContentTemplate="{TemplateBinding ContentTemplate}"
                                                        Content="{TemplateBinding Content}"
                                                        HorizontalAlignment="{TemplateBinding HorizontalContentAlignment}"
                                                        VerticalAlignment="{TemplateBinding VerticalContentAlignment}"
                                                        Margin="{TemplateBinding Padding}" />
                                </Grid>
                            </Border>
                        </Border>
                    </Grid>
                </Border>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [ListViewItem styles and templates](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/mt299136.aspx) doesn't have `SelectionStates` VisualStateGroups. So the `ListViewItem` style doesn't manage your `selected` view state in the `SelectionStates` well. Move the `Selected` VisualState to the `CommonStates` VisualStateGroup. And it will work.
Updated code as follows:

```
 <Setter Property="Template">
     <Setter.Value>
         <ControlTemplate TargetType="ListViewItem">
             <Border x:Name="OuterContainer" RenderTransformOrigin="0.5,0.5">
                 <VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                     <VisualStateGroup x:Name="CommonStates">
                         <VisualState x:Name="Normal">
                                    <!--  unselektiert  -->
                                    <Storyboard>
                                        <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Duration="0"
                                                                       Storyboard.TargetName="ContentBorder"
                                                                       Storyboard.TargetProperty="BorderBrush">
                                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="Orange" />
                                        </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                        <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Duration="0"
                                                                       Storyboard.TargetName="ContentBorder"
                                                                       Storyboard.TargetProperty="Background">
                                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="LightBlue" />
                                        </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                        <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Duration="0"
                                                                       Storyboard.TargetName="ContentBorder"
                                                                       Storyboard.TargetProperty="Margin">
                                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="0 0 0 2" />
                                        </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                    </Storyboard>
                                </VisualState>                      
                         <VisualState x:Name="Pressed">
                                    <!--  Klick  -->
                                    <Storyboard>
                                        <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Duration="0"
                                                                       Storyboard.TargetName="ContentBorder"
                                                                       Storyboard.TargetProperty="BorderBrush">
                                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="Red" />
                                        </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                        <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Duration="0"
                                                                       Storyboard.TargetName="ContentBorder"
                                                                       Storyboard.TargetProperty="Background">
                                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="Blue" />
                                        </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                        <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Duration="0"
                                                                       Storyboard.TargetName="ContentBorder"
                                                                       Storyboard.TargetProperty="Margin">
                                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="2 2 2 4" />
                                        </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                    </Storyboard>
                                </VisualState>   
                         <VisualState x:Name="Selected">
                                    <!--  Selektiert  -->
                                    <Storyboard>
                                        <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Duration="0"
                                                                       Storyboard.TargetName="ContentBorder"
                                                                       Storyboard.TargetProperty="BorderBrush">
                                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="DarkRed" />
                                        </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                        <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Duration="0"
                                                                       Storyboard.TargetName="ContentBorder"
                                                                       Storyboard.TargetProperty="Background">
                                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="DarkBlue" />
                                        </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                        <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Duration="0"
                                                                       Storyboard.TargetName="ContentBorder"
                                                                       Storyboard.TargetProperty="Margin">
                                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="0 0 0 2" />
                                        </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                    </Storyboard>
                                </VisualState>                     
                     </VisualStateGroup>                                        
                 </VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                 <Grid x:Name="ReorderHintContent" Background="Transparent">
                            <Border x:Name="ContentContainer">
                                <Border x:Name="ContentBorder"
                                        Background="LightCyan"
                                        BorderBrush="DarkCyan"
                                        BorderThickness="2">
                                    <Grid>
                                        <ContentPresenter x:Name="contentPresenter"
                                                          Margin="{TemplateBinding Padding}"
                                                          HorizontalAlignment="{TemplateBinding HorizontalContentAlignment}"
                                                          VerticalAlignment="{TemplateBinding VerticalContentAlignment}"
                                                          Content="{TemplateBinding Content}"
                                                          ContentTemplate="{TemplateBinding ContentTemplate}"
                                                          ContentTransitions="{TemplateBinding ContentTransitions}" />
                                    </Grid>
                                </Border>
                            </Border>
                        </Grid>
             </Border>
         </ControlTemplate>
     </Setter.Value>
 </Setter>
```